# How could I create a time lapsed image

Tags: video

How can I create a time lapsed image like [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Rajnikant_Sharma/publication/304816948/figure/fig11/AS:667925484695559@1536257253259/Time-lapse-image-of-the-quadrotor-following-a-circular-path-in-the-capture-volume-at-RISC.ppm)? (they are the same drone at 6 different time instances)
[image]
I am not a professional video editor, but rather just an end user.
So is there any online service or free software that allows me to achieve this effect? My video is shot from a tripod and the camera is not moved/zoomed during the whole process.

Comment: Just to get some clarification: The drone flew 6 times through the same area, and then you want to overlap those 6 flights, as if they flew togehter?

Comment: No, actually, the drone only flies once, and I record a video of its flying. I just would like to plot an image that shows the drone at different time instances so that the viewer could see the shape of its flying trajectory.

Comment: Ouh, I think I get it now. You mean, like you've would have done a long exposure image. You can check out this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8L9eGQZNKs This tutorial uses PS. A free alternative would be GIMP with this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JzEPpH7CT7w

Comment: I don't have an answer, but the above notions are good; (whether its hidden or expicit) _any_ plugin/workflow will first need an empty backdrop rendered. You can grab some varied still frames and combine them in tools like the open-source software Hugin ([example](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12724/what-open-source-software-for-auto-alignment-of-photographs)). The empty image will then be used as the baseline for a video-effect processor called an _image keyer_. I don't know of a free keyer or free nle with keying features/plugins. Good luck.